# conditional branch in groovy code based on state

Tags: jenkins, groovy, gitlab

I have a webhook in gitlab, that triggers a Jenkins job which run a groovy script.

Now I want that the branch to checkout will be conditional:

- If the state is merged to take the `target_branch` and if not that the `source_branch`

I couldn't find exactly how to do it in the groovy code. The triggers are different for one is note and for the other is merge request

Answer (score 0):

There are gitlab variables that are passed: https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#defined-variables

so the following solved my issue:

```
// Distniguish between 2 types of webhook triggers
if(env.gitlabMergeRequestState != null) {
    merge_status = "merged"
    if (merge_status.equalsIgnoreCase(env.gitlabMergeRequestState)) {
        echo "Merged Trigger, using: ${env.gitlabTargetBranch} branch"
        branch = env.gitlabTargetBranch
    } else {
        echo "Note Trigger, using: ${env.gitlabSourceBranch} branch"
        branch = env.gitlabSourceBranch
    }
}
```